# Algebraic dependent summation of transcendental numbers.

Tags: real-analysis, transcendental-numbers

Question if $a$ and $b$ are both transcendental but algebraically dependent over Q. what do we know about $(a+b)$? In particular is there a way to bring $(xa^y+nb^m)$ where $x,y,n,m$ are rational and $n,m$ not equal zero to an algebraic number?

Comment: Sometimes $a+b$ is algebraic, sometimes it isn't.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I get that it can be seen with a=b=pi. But in that case b-a is algebraic. My question is can we bring (a+b) to an algebraic number by rational multiplication to a or b, or performing something on a or b that makes (a+b) algebraic.

Comment: The example I had in mind was $a=4-\pi$, $b=\pi$. What does bring $a+b$ to an algebraic number mean?

Comment: @AndréNicolas I changed the question to clarify.